# Validation on Next/Previous divs

Tags: jquery

I have a quiz section on a webpage, all the questions get loaded at once, (like Google Forms). I want to show one question at a time, so after choosing an option we can move to the next question using the Next/Previous buttons.

So far I have, all the divs hidden by default, except the first one.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#quiz .section").each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
      $(this).hide();
  });

  $("#next").click(function() {
    if ($("#quiz div.section:visible").next().length != 0)
      if ($('.form-group input:checked').length == 0) {
        alert('Please select and Option');
      } else {
        $("#quiz div.section:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
      }
    else {
      $("#quiz div.section:visible").hide();
      $("#quiz div.section:first").show();
    }
    return false;
  });

  $("#prev").click(function() {
    if ($("#quiz div.section:visible").prev().length != 0)
      $("#quiz div.section:visible").prev().show().next().hide();
    else {
      $("#quiz div.section:visible").hide();
      $("#quiz div.section:last").show();
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="online-mcqs-submit.asp" autocomplete="off" id="validator">
  <input type="hidden" name="mcqs" value="submit">
  <div id='quiz'>
    <div class='section' id='sec1'>
      <div class='col-md-8 col-md-offset-2' style='padding:20px;border:1px solid #ccc;background:#fff'>
        <div class='col-md-2 text-center'>
          <h3><span class='label label-info'>1</span></h3>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-10'>
          <h4>In preparing a program, one shoud first</h4>
          <div class='form-group'>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_1" value="1" required> plan the solution</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_1" value="2" required> document the program</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_1" value="3" required> code the program</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_1" value="4" required> define the problem</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='section' id='sec2'>
      <div class='col-md-8 col-md-offset-2' style='padding:20px;border:1px solid #ccc;background:#fff'>
        <div class='col-md-2 text-center'>
          <h3><span class='label label-info'>2</span></h3>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-10'>
          <h4>Which of the following is used to design a program using English-like statements?</h4>
          <div class='form-group'>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_2" value="1" required> Algorithm</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_2" value="2" required> program flowchart</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_2" value="3" required> control structure</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_2" value="4" required> None of the above</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='section' id='sec3'>
      <div class='col-md-8 col-md-offset-2' style='padding:20px;border:1px solid #ccc;background:#fff'>
        <div class='col-md-2 text-center'>
          <h3><span class='label label-info'>3</span></h3>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-10'>
          <h4>Compilers and interpreters are types of _______________</h4>
          <div class='form-group'>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_3" value="1" required> Programming languages</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_3" value="2" required> language translators</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_3" value="3" required> alpha testers</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_3" value="4" required> application generators</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='section' id='sec4'>
      <div class='col-md-8 col-md-offset-2' style='padding:20px;border:1px solid #ccc;background:#fff'>
        <div class='col-md-2 text-center'>
          <h3><span class='label label-info'>4</span></h3>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-10'>
          <h4>Which of the following type of error is detected by a language translator?</h4>
          <div class='form-group'>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_4" value="1" required> program design</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_4" value="2" required> logic</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_4" value="3" required> syntax</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_4" value="4" required> both b and c</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='section' id='sec5'>
      <div class='col-md-8 col-md-offset-2' style='padding:20px;border:1px solid #ccc;background:#fff'>
        <div class='col-md-2 text-center'>
          <h3><span class='label label-info'>5</span></h3>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-10'>
          <h4>You test a program to find which of the following?</h4>
          <div class='form-group'>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_5" value="1" required> flowcharting errors</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_5" value="2" required> logic errors</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_5" value="3" required> algorithmic errors</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_5" value="4" required> syntax errors</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6"><a id="prev" class="btn btn-default">Previous</a></div>
      <div class="col-md-6"><a id="next" class="btn btn-default">Next</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-8 col-md-offset-2' style='margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:20px;'>
      <input type="hidden" value="23" name="rowcount">
      <input type='submit' value='SUBMIT' class='btn btn-lg btn-block btn-success'>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**The Problem:**

Right now when I click on the Next button, it gives the alert to choose an option, but for all other questions, the validation is not working.

- I want to apply validation on each question/div before going to the next
  question/div.
- I want to show submit button on the last question/div.
- I want to disable the previous button on the last question/div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is update the `selector` from your `if` of alert code. Add `#quiz div.section:visible`  at beginning of your selector so that it will check for `.form-group input:checked` inside `#quiz div.section:visible`  only.

Use `if ($('#quiz div.section:visible .form-group input:checked').length == 0) {`

Add `showHideSubmitButton();` as per below code and call it from next/prev button click. Also call it from `document.ready` as well so it will initially hide submit button.

Add selector inside `next('div.section')` & `prev('div.section')` so it will select correct div.

Try complete code below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#quiz .section").each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
      $(this).hide();
  });
  
  showHideSubmitButton();

  $("#next").click(function() {
    if ($("#quiz div.section:visible").next('div.section').length != 0)
      if ($('#quiz div.section:visible .form-group input:checked').length == 0) {
        alert('Please select and Option');
      } else {
        $("#quiz div.section:visible").hide().next('div.section').show();
      }
    else {
      $("#quiz div.section:visible").hide();
      $("#quiz div.section:first").show();
    }
    showHideSubmitButton();
    return false;
  });

  $("#prev").click(function() {
    if ($("#quiz div.section:visible").prev('div.section').length != 0)
      $("#quiz div.section:visible").hide().prev('div.section').show();
    else {
      $("#quiz div.section:visible").hide();
      $("#quiz div.section:last").show();
    }
    showHideSubmitButton();
    return false;
  });

  function showHideSubmitButton() {
    if ($("#quiz div.section:visible").next('div.section').length == 0) {
      $('input[type=submit]').show();
      $('#next').hide();
    } else {
      $('input[type=submit]').hide();
      $('#next').show();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="online-mcqs-submit.asp" autocomplete="off" id="validator">
  <input type="hidden" name="mcqs" value="submit">
  <div id='quiz'>
    <div class='section' id='sec1'>
      <div class='col-md-8 col-md-offset-2' style='padding:20px;border:1px solid #ccc;background:#fff'>
        <div class='col-md-2 text-center'>
          <h3><span class='label label-info'>1</span></h3>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-10'>
          <h4>In preparing a program, one shoud first</h4>
          <div class='form-group'>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_1" value="1" required> plan the solution</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_1" value="2" required> document the program</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_1" value="3" required> code the program</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_1" value="4" required> define the problem</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='section' id='sec2'>
      <div class='col-md-8 col-md-offset-2' style='padding:20px;border:1px solid #ccc;background:#fff'>
        <div class='col-md-2 text-center'>
          <h3><span class='label label-info'>2</span></h3>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-10'>
          <h4>Which of the following is used to design a program using English-like statements?</h4>
          <div class='form-group'>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_2" value="1" required> Algorithm</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_2" value="2" required> program flowchart</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_2" value="3" required> control structure</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_2" value="4" required> None of the above</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='section' id='sec3'>
      <div class='col-md-8 col-md-offset-2' style='padding:20px;border:1px solid #ccc;background:#fff'>
        <div class='col-md-2 text-center'>
          <h3><span class='label label-info'>3</span></h3>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-10'>
          <h4>Compilers and interpreters are types of _______________</h4>
          <div class='form-group'>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_3" value="1" required> Programming languages</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_3" value="2" required> language translators</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_3" value="3" required> alpha testers</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_3" value="4" required> application generators</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='section' id='sec4'>
      <div class='col-md-8 col-md-offset-2' style='padding:20px;border:1px solid #ccc;background:#fff'>
        <div class='col-md-2 text-center'>
          <h3><span class='label label-info'>4</span></h3>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-10'>
          <h4>Which of the following type of error is detected by a language translator?</h4>
          <div class='form-group'>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_4" value="1" required> program design</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_4" value="2" required> logic</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_4" value="3" required> syntax</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_4" value="4" required> both b and c</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='section' id='sec5'>
      <div class='col-md-8 col-md-offset-2' style='padding:20px;border:1px solid #ccc;background:#fff'>
        <div class='col-md-2 text-center'>
          <h3><span class='label label-info'>5</span></h3>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-10'>
          <h4>You test a program to find which of the following?</h4>
          <div class='form-group'>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_5" value="1" required> flowcharting errors</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_5" value="2" required> logic errors</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_5" value="3" required> algorithmic errors</label><br>
            <label><input type="radio" name="sans_5" value="4" required> syntax errors</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6"><a id="prev" class="btn btn-default">Previous</a></div>
      <div class="col-md-6"><a id="next" class="btn btn-default">Next</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-8 col-md-offset-2' style='margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:20px;'>
      <input type="hidden" value="23" name="rowcount">
      <input type='submit' value='SUBMIT' class='btn btn-lg btn-block btn-success'>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix Karan. now I am getting prompt for each question. How can prevent next button at the last question? How can I show the submit button on last question (which is hidden in CSS)?

Comment: I've updated the answer. In your question you mentioned to hide `previous` button and in comment here you mention to hide `next` button. I believe you want to hide `next` button only. Can you please confirm which button you want to hide?

Comment: Yes, I mean the Next button at the end.

Comment: Updated answer to hide `next` button at the end.

Comment: Thanks for putting much efforts and helping out :-) one request though, if possible please comment out key functions for me and for future visitors. So we can modify as per needed. (e.g disabling previous button on 1st question/div)